# QMessageBox open multiple times using shortcutkeys

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am putting a QMesssageBox inline with the shortcutkey of CTRL + N (it means new file will be open). When I press and hold the shortcut key when the object is animating. Is it UI problem of Linux since I am using Linux OS and then I try in other OS and it is not happening, or any codes that I forgot? 
Thank you.

Comment: provide  a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to have at most one QMessageBox appear at a time, you can ensure that in your code via something like this:

```
static QMessageBox * openMBox = NULL;

void MyClass :: showMessageBox()
{
   if (openMBox) return;  // don't open a new QMessageBox if we already have one open!

   openMBox = new QMessageBox(args here...);
   connect(openMBox, SIGNAL(buttonClicked(QAbstractButton*)), this, SLOT(userClickedButton(QAbstractButton*)));
   openMBox->show();
}

void MyClass :: userClickedButton(QAbstractButton * button)
{
   if (openMBox)
   {
      // [code to handle button-click result could go here]

      openMBox->deleteLater();
      openMBox = NULL;
   }
}
```

Note that `showMessageBox()` will only actually create a new `QMessageBox` if `openMBox` is NULL, which is to say, only if there isn't already a message-box present.

(The code calls `deleteLater()` in the `userClickedButton()` method instead of using the delete operator because it's likely that the `userClickedButton()` method is itself being called from within a method of the `QMessageBox` object, therefore we don't want to delete the `QMessageBox` object until later when it's not in the middle of a method-call)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I got some idea from the codes you give.